# Move to new workbook as values by tab color?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, copy

I have a large report with multiple data tables and about 12-20 sheets of broken out reports.  What I currently have to do is Move/Copy, all the tabs, and then go through and copy and paste values to drop the pivot references.  I've color coded which ones should be grouped together.

I am a VBA novice for sure, but wanted to know if someone could help me out.  Is there anyway to reference tab color in VBA?  If so could someone provide a quick code that might do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a tab has had a color assigned then

```
Activesheet.Tab.Color
```

will return the RGB value (as a Long).  If no color has been assigned it returns `False`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but in addition to what Tim said you can access the color of a tab by using the color index, for example:

```
ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex
```

This returns a number that matches simple colors.

There is a table that you might find usful for this here:
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

To loop through your sheets you could write a simple loop such as:

```
Dim Sheetcount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Sheetcount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To Sheetcount
  If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Tab.ColorIndex = 3 Then 'just an example color
         'your code here
Next i
```